# How to use deprecated cas plugin for SonarQube 4.5 authentication

Tags: sonarqube, cas

Could you please help me to integrate cas plugin for SonarQube 4.5 authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin has been deprecated since SonarQube 3.3, so there's no way to use it in 4.5 - unless you grab the code and try to update it on your own (but I would not advise you to do so as it might be actually impossible).

Comment: so is there any other way to do single sign for Sonar with other applications.

Comment: The current reference implementation is the OpenID plugin. And we'll soon provide a plugin based on http header authentication.

Comment: Does this openid plugin only supports google account or it can be worked with cas. if we integtres openid support to cas as it mentioned here https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/OpenID